# Heap sort with multithreading

Tags: c#, multithreading, algorithm, sorting, heapsort

I need to improve *general heap sort* using C# multithreading.
I don't have a clear idea about implementation of improvements.

One of the suggestions I got is to separate arrays for *N* parts and heapsort each part in specific thread.
And then merge each ordered part of array.
In this case I think it will not be so efficient because of merging in general stream after using heapsort.

Can you suggest other ideas?
Or maybe if it will be not efficient, do you have any ideas how I can use multithreading in in heap sort in a different way?

Comment: (Upvoted for *interesting problem*, not for *well researched*.)

Comment: What problem do you see with *merging in general stream after using heapsort*?

Comment: It looks like over coding for just using multithreading instead of single thread, it will work and complexity will remain n x log(n), but I suppose there is better way to use multithreading for heapsort, which I didn't find.

Comment: *Nothing* using key comparison and limited resources can possibly better heapsort's asymptotic complexity. Don't ask me whether using merge sort with concurrent threads/distributed memory/computers using heapsort "for the chunks" is an improved heapsort or merge sort.

Comment: I just added phrase about the complexity as a comment, it will not affect on complexity of algorithm of course, you are right

Comment: I get several plausible results searching for "parallel heap sort algorithm"

Comment: (@Dave: if you think those findings would improve the question, here's from the guidance to [editing posts](/help/editing): *reasons to edit a post are: • To clarify the meaning of the post (without changing that meaning) • To add related resources or hyperlinks*.)

Comment: @greybeard I don't, but thank you, and feel free to go ahead if you do.

Comment: You can easily parallelize the first step of creating the max heap by having each thread max heapify a subtree and then do the rest in a single thread. But I think the 2nd part has to be sequential.

Comment: The "most heapsort" approach to parallel sorting I came across is G.S. Eduneer's [Dualheap Sort Algorithm](https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/0706/0706.2893.pdf), *An Inherently Parallel Generalization of Heapsort*.

Answer (score 0):

I find it hard to believe that multi-threading would not impose more overhead than it is worth here.

Still, I would think of it like this. Each thread heapsorts a chunk of data. Then you do the merge with a heapsort on the chunks. Where your heap of chunks is ordered by the next value that will be used. So you take a chunk off, add the value to the sorted list, move the pointer in the chunk by one, then add it to the heap.

If you're clever about [building pipelines](https://michaelscodingspot.com/pipeline-pattern-implementations-csharp/), you should be able to start the heap-merge while the individual heap-sorts are going on. But there is an excellent chance that context switching will be too heavyweight for this to work well.

Comment: I wouldn't call this *heapsort on the chunks*, but *multi-way merge of ordered streams (from concurrent heapsorts) using another heap*. The usual concern with merge sort applies: How much additional memory is consumed when the sort is allowed to be in-place?

Comment: @greybeard Yes, it is a multiway merge, using a heap just like a heapsort I'm pretty indifferent about what to call things like this.